# Why are extra applications necessary for hosting Git via "smart HTTP" in IIS?

Tags: git, iis-7, cgi, iis-7.5

As the title indicates, I am wondering about the fact, that it seems to be not possible to host Git repos only via the CGI application `git-http-backend` in IIS.
I thought that CGI applications are somehow "portable" between web servers, but every guide and tutorial about creating an own Git server under IIS does this by using e.g. an ASP.NET application handling the requests.

So my question is:
What exactly prevents using the IIS CGI module in combination with the `git-http-backend`?